# AttributeError for analyzing multiple sheets in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, spreadsheet, xlsx

I included `sheet_name=None` to analyze every sheet but then I have a problem with reading `columns`.

```
import pandas

df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', sheet_name=None, index_col=[0])

df.columns = df.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
```

I got this error message

```
    df.columns = df.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'columns'
```

It is working perfectly on one sheet, why won't work for multiple sheets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
dfs = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', sheet_name=None, index_col=[0])

with pd.ExcelWriter('output_file.xlsx') as writer:
    for name, df in dfs.items():
        print(name)
        df.columns = df.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Pandas doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)

> sheet_namestr, int, list, or None, default 0
> Strings are used for sheet names. Integers are used in zero-indexed sheet positions. Lists of strings/integers are used to request multiple sheets. Specify None to get all sheets.

This means when `sheet_name`is specified as `None`, Pandas load all your sheets as separate `DataFrame`s and store them in a `dict` with sheet names as keys and the corresponding `DataFrame` as values.

To achieve a similar effect, you may want:

```
df_dict = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', sheet_name=None, index_col=[0])
for name, df in df_dict.items():
    df.columns = df.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
```

Comment: it is not working properly. Actually it might do what it need to do, and overrides data from last sheet. I only get a data from last sheet.

Answer (score 0):

When you specify `sheet_name` as `None` then that returns `dict`, that is why you are getting that `'dict' object has no attribute 'columns'` but if you want to get the DataFrame then you can try this :

```
for key in df:
     df[key].columns = df[key].columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
     print(df[key].head())
```

But if you know the exact name of sheet that you want then do this :

```
df["<>"].column=df["<>"].columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
```

For more information about all these visit [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html#pandas-read-excel)

> `sheet_name` : str, int, list, or None, default 0
>
> Strings are used for sheet names. Integers are used in zero-indexed sheet positions. Lists of strings/integers are used to request multiple sheets. Specify None to get all sheets.
>
> Available cases:
>
> Defaults to 0: 1st sheet as a DataFrame
>
> 1: 2nd sheet as a DataFrame
>
> "Sheet1": Load sheet with name “Sheet1”
>
> [0, 1, "Sheet5"]: Load first, second and sheet named “Sheet5” as a dict of DataFrame
>
> None: All sheets.

Comment: I don't know names of sheets and I don't know how many sheets there are. Can you please tell me what in this line `print(data[key].head())` represents `data`?

Comment: Sorry my bad I am trying to write df but accidentally I wrote data. :)

Comment: this work but after this i get this `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'stack'`, after this i run `new_data = df.stack(0)`. Why do I get this error now?

Comment: You have added that, right? I don't think I have that line in my answer.

Comment: Yes, after your code i add this. Your code is working, and I'm trying to do what I need to do. How do I comply my code with your solution?

Comment: You had done wrong, your dataframe is present in `df[key]` that `df` is `dict`. Haven't I clearly told you about that in answer. And you told it is working, if it works mark as an accepted answer, and give upvote if you like my effort. :)